# How to get return value (double type) from function in DLL?

Tags: go, dll

I have a Windows DLL (Win32 builded) with signature

```
double PASCAL EXPORT GetData(DWORD DN, DWORD channel, DWORD type, DWORD aver, DWORD parN);
```

It always return value from `00.00` to `100.00` and I try to call it from `GO`

```
var err error
var rt, rt2 uintptr

dll := syscall.NewLazyDLL("SomeLib.dll")
rt, rt2, err = dll.NewProc("O110_GetData").Call(
    uintptr(int(0)),
    uintptr(int(0)),
    uintptr(int(2)),
    uintptr(int(6)),
    uintptr(int(2)))

log.Printf("RT2.3=", math.Float32frombits(uint32(rt2)))
log.Printf("RT2.4=", math.Float64frombits(uint64(rt2)))
```

As I see, value returned in `rt2`.
But I get impossible result.

How can I convert result (`double`) in `uintptr` to `float32`?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, this is a bug - at the moment on GO it is impossible to get double result from windows DLL